# Getting duplicate entries in row with primary key

Tags: php, mysql

When records are added in a loop and there are duplicates in the added data they still get added to mysql table even though the duplicated field is the primary key.
How can this happen and how do I stop it?
Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: may be some space issue is there. can you please check?

Comment: How're you inserting records in DB?

Comment: @BhavinSolanki is correct. It might be there is some space in the left of the text. Check once.

Comment: there are no spaces I typed test myself and made sure of it.
added via php:
$xsql = "INSERT INTO members (email) VALUES ('$email')";
$retval = mysql_query( $xsql, $conn );

Comment: Export the table and show us the duplicate line

Comment: try this sql and paste me the result: select concat('A',email,'A') from members limit 0,30

Comment: @Arun:
exporting the data showed me the problem. I was using a textarea to enter the data and did not press enter at the end of the 2nd entry so the first line had lf or cr in it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with my server and found that,

- if we give space before text then it will consider and insert data without any duplicate error.

UPDATE test.blog SET title = ' title1' WHERE blog.title = ' title1';

[image]
- If we give space before text then it will give duplicate email error.

[image]

Comment: as mentioned there is definitely no space

Comment: if you look at the structure it is unique. I thought primary had to be unique. I set it as unique anyway, deleted old records, same result

Comment: @EdNewman primary key is only worked on integer value try to check the email before submitting the record

Comment: @Pardeep that is not true. It works fine with text fields also. problem was in how I was entering the data and is working now.

Comment: Great if it is working. What was the problem anyway? Were there spaces?

Comment: it was something at the end. not a space. linefeed, cr, etc that came from a textarea

Answer (score 1):

There is no other case where you can insert same value in primary key field. Either you have space before the string ' test' or you haven't assign primary field properly.

Can you please type an insert query directly in mysql with duplicate values and let me know if you are getting an error.

```
INSERT INTO `members`(`email`) VALUES ('test'),('test')
```